# Piklist File Upload

Tags: post-meta

I am doing this tutorial: https://piklist.com/user-guide/tutorials/displaying-images-upload-field/

After creating this for a custom post type:

```
// Upload Image / File
  piklist('field', array(
  'type' => 'file'
  ,'field' => 'my_image'
  ,'label' => 'Upload image'
));
```

I then follwed by doing this

```
$image_ids = get_post_meta($post_id, 'my_image');
but now I am trying to call:

 print_r($image_ids);
```

and no array gets output.

what am I doing wrong? How do I get the images uploaded in the custom postype?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey try to use this i think it work fine

```
$image_ids = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'my_image');   
print_r($image_ids);
```

Comment: that and this $post->ID  works as well, any ideas why the other one does not